# Tangent plane of a surface and a curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors, parametric

I'm trying to find the equation of the tangent plane of a surface, at a given point $\vec{a}$

For a surface, say $f(x,y,z)=0$, this is how I'd normally find the tangent plane :

$\hat{n} = \frac{\vec\nabla f(x,y,z)}{|\vec\nabla f(x,y,z)|}$.

This is the unit normal to the surface. Then we can say that, the tangent plane is given by :

$(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\hat{n} = 0 $

From here, we can easily obtain the equation of the tangent plane in the cartesian form $ax+by+cz=0$.

Now, here is my first doubt.

In cartesian coordinates, doesn't the equation $ax+by+cz=0$ represent both a plane and a curve. Moreover, the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ represents both a curve, as well as a surface. How do we know, if we are getting a tangent line or a tangent plane, or that the equation represents a curve or a surface?

My guess is, we can differentiate if we are using the parametric form, because in the case of curves, we need one parameter, and for surfaces, we need two. However, I still don't know how can we go from cartesian representation to parametric representation, for $ax+by+cz=0$ in the first place, if we don't know if it's a line or a plane.

Suppose, we have the equations giving in parametric forms.

For a **curve**, we have $\vec{r_c}=f(t)\hat{i} + g(t)\hat{j}+ h(t)\hat{k}$.

For a **surface**, it becomes $\vec{r_c}=f(u,v)\hat{i} + g(u,v)\hat{j}+ h(u,v)\hat{k}$.

However, given in this form, how do we find the tangent/tangent plane since we cannot use the gradient operator anymore?

For the curve, we can just take the partial w.r.t to the variable $t$, at the point $\vec{a}$, and that will give us the tangent vector ( not the tangent plane ). We have found the vector parallel to the plane and passing through the plane. How do I find the normal vector to this point, in order to find an expression for the tangent plane ? Basically, $(\vec{r}-\vec{a})\hat{n}=0$ and I've managed to find a vector parallel to $(\vec{r}-\vec{a})$ at that point. How do I proceed?

However, how do I do this for the parametric surface? My intuition is to take the partial with respect to the parametric variables $u$ and $v$ , and then take the cross product to get the normal vector, and hence the tangent plane.

Is this intuition correct?

Can anyone clear these doubts for me? How to know if an expression represents a curve or a surface in cartesian coordinates, and how do I find the tangent plane to them, in parametric form? How do I find the tangent plane to a **curve** in parametric form?

Comment: Assuming $a,b,c$ are not simultaneously $0$, the set of points $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3\,:\, ax+by+cz=0\}$ is a plane (a $3-1=2$-dimensional vector space). Why do you say it represents a curve/line?

Comment: For a curve, $\vec{r}(t) = (f(t), g(t), h(t))$, the tangent vector is $r'(t) = (f'(t), g'(t), h'(t))$ and you can normalize it. Similarly for a parametrized surface in the form you wrote later, $r_u \times r_v$ is a normal vector to the surface and again you can normalize it to find unit normal.

Comment: @peek-a-boo how do I then represent a line between two points in three dimensions. A general equation for a line in 3-d, but not in parametric form, in cartesian form.

Comment: $x = a + b t, y = c + d t, z = e + ft$ is a line where $(b, d, f)$ is direction vector and $(a, c, e)$ is a point on the line or we write as $\frac{x-a}{b} = \frac{y-c}{d} = \frac{z-e}{f}$.

Comment: @MathLover how do I write it in a non-parametric form? Is it at all possible to do this? As in how can a represent a line in 3d in $f(x,y,z) = 0$ form?

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay Writing it parametrically is the simplest, but one can also express it as an intersection of two planes (with some caveats). For example, the set of points $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3\,:\, \text{$a_1x+b_1y+c_1z=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z=0$}\}$ where $(a_1,b_1,c_1), (a_2,b_2,c_2)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ are linearly independent (i.e both are non-zero and neither is a scalar multiple of the other) describes a line. In other words, we're considering a surjective linear transformation $T:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^2$. Then, $\ker T=\{\xi\,: T(\xi)=0\}$ is a line (google rank-nullity theorem for more).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much. Another small doubt. FOr a surface, we find the tangent plane using the normal vector, and for a curve, we find the tangent vector and not the tangent plane. But how can we take the parametric form of a curve, and find the tangent plane, and not the tangent vector ?

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay you cannot write it as $f(x, y, z) = 0$ but you can write some of the simple curves as intersection of $f(x, y, z) = 0$ and $g(x, y, z) = 0$. For example, many simple curves are intersection of a surface and a plane.

Comment: curves do not have tangent planes; only tangent lines. Generally, $k$-dimensional "objects" (manifolds to be precise) have $k$-dimensional tangent spaces.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Your intuition is correct.  For a parametrically specified surface, find $\dfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u} $ and $\dfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial v} $, then find their cross product,

$ \vec{n} = \dfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u} \times \dfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial v} $

then $\vec{n}$ is a normal vector to the surface, at $\vec{a}$, which you can use to find the equation of the tangent plane, as follows:

$\vec{n} \cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{a}) = 0 $